# NSRange to Range<String.Index>

Tags: nsstring, swift, ios8, nsrange

How can I convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` in Swift?

I want to use the following `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField!,
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
        replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {

textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(???, withString: string)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Apple, for giving us the new Range class, but then not updating of any of the string utility classes, such as NSRegularExpression, to use them!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233619/2303865

Answer (score 275, accepted):

The `NSString` version (as opposed to Swift String) of `replacingCharacters(in: NSRange, with: NSString)` accepts an `NSRange`, so one simple solution is to **convert `String` to `NSString` first**. The delegate and replacement method names are slightly different in Swift 3 and 2, so depending on which Swift you're using:

#### Swift 3.0

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  let nsString = textField.text as NSString?
  let newString = nsString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
}
```

#### Swift 2.x

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let nsString = textField.text as NSString?
    let newString = nsString?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
}
```

Comment: This will not work if `textField` contains multi-code unit unicode characters such as emoji. Since it is an entry field a user may well enter emoji (), other page 1 characters of multi code unit characters such as flags ().

Comment: @Zaph: since the range comes from the UITextField, which is written in Obj-C against NSString, I suspect that only valid ranges based on the unicode characters in the string would be provided by the delegate callback, and so this is safe to use, but I haven't personally tested it.

Comment: Unicode, all of it, is supported by `NSString` and given a `UITextField` a user may well enter multi UTF-16 bit unicode character. `NSString` is UTF-16 based and works with UTF-16 units and will return the number of UTF-16 units, not characters. Thus a `NSRange` may start or end inside a unicode character such as an emoji. There are also unicode surrogate pairs in plane 0 as well.

Comment: @Zaph, that's true, my point is that `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method won't provide a range which starts or ends inside a unicode character, since the callback is based on a user entering characters from the keyboard, and it's not possible to type only part of an emoji unicode character. Note that if the delegate were written in Obj-C, it would have this same problem.

Comment: Not the best answer. Easiest to read code but @martin-r has the correct answer.

Comment: Actually you guys should do this
`(textField.text as NSString?)?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)`

Comment: @harishmistry: I've added a Swift 3.0 version, hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Shorter Swift 3 version if an empty string is OK when textField.text is nil: `((textField.text ?? "") as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`

Answer (score 414):

As of **Swift 4** (Xcode 9), the Swift standard
library provides methods to convert between Swift string ranges
(`Range<String.Index>`)  and `NSString` ranges (`NSRange`).
Example:

```
let str = "abc"
let r1 = str.range(of: "")!

// String range to NSRange:
let n1 = NSRange(r1, in: str)
print((str as NSString).substring(with: n1)) // 

// NSRange back to String range:
let r2 = Range(n1, in: str)!
print(str[r2]) //
```

Therefore the text replacement in the text field delegate method
can now be done as

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let oldString = textField.text {
        let newString = oldString.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: oldString)!,
                                                      with: string)
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

*(Older answers for Swift 3 and earlier:)*

As of Swift 1.2, `String.Index` has an initializer

```
init?(_ utf16Index: UTF16Index, within characters: String)
```

which can be used to convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` correctly
(including all cases of Emojis, Regional Indicators or other extended
grapheme clusters) without intermediate conversion to an `NSString`:

```
extension String {
    func rangeFromNSRange(nsRange : NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        let from16 = advance(utf16.startIndex, nsRange.location, utf16.endIndex)
        let to16 = advance(from16, nsRange.length, utf16.endIndex)
        if let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: self) {
                return from ..< to
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This method returns an *optional* string range because not all `NSRange`s
are valid for a given Swift string.

The `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate method can then be written as

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let swRange = textField.text.rangeFromNSRange(range) {
        let newString = textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(swRange, withString: string)
        // ...
    }
    return true
}
```

The inverse conversion is

```
extension String {
    func NSRangeFromRange(range : Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
        let utf16view = self.utf16
        let from = String.UTF16View.Index(range.startIndex, within: utf16view) 
        let to = String.UTF16View.Index(range.endIndex, within: utf16view)
        return NSMakeRange(from - utf16view.startIndex, to - from)
    }
}
```

A simple test:

```
let str = "abc"
let r1 = str.rangeOfString("")!

// String range to NSRange:
let n1 = str.NSRangeFromRange(r1)
println((str as NSString).substringWithRange(n1)) // 

// NSRange back to String range:
let r2 = str.rangeFromNSRange(n1)!
println(str.substringWithRange(r2)) //
```

**Update for Swift 2:**

The Swift 2 version of `rangeFromNSRange()` was already given 
by Serhii Yakovenko in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32379600/1187415), I am including it
here for completeness:

```
extension String {
    func rangeFromNSRange(nsRange : NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        let from16 = utf16.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location, limit: utf16.endIndex)
        let to16 = from16.advancedBy(nsRange.length, limit: utf16.endIndex)
        if let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: self) {
                return from ..< to
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The Swift 2 version of `NSRangeFromRange()` is

```
extension String {
    func NSRangeFromRange(range : Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
        let utf16view = self.utf16
        let from = String.UTF16View.Index(range.startIndex, within: utf16view)
        let to = String.UTF16View.Index(range.endIndex, within: utf16view)
        return NSMakeRange(utf16view.startIndex.distanceTo(from), from.distanceTo(to))
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
extension String {
    func nsRange(from range: Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
        let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16)
        let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16)
        return NSRange(location: utf16.distance(from: utf16.startIndex, to: from),
                       length: utf16.distance(from: from, to: to))
    }
}

extension String {
    func range(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        guard
            let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let to16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location + nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let from = from16.samePosition(in: self),
            let to = to16.samePosition(in: self)
            else { return nil }
        return from ..< to
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let str = "abc"
let r1 = str.range(of: "")!

// String range to NSRange:
let n1 = str.nsRange(from: r1)
print((str as NSString).substring(with: n1)) // 

// NSRange back to String range:
let r2 = str.range(from: n1)!
print(str.substring(with: r2)) //
```

Comment: Why not just do http://stackoverflow.com/a/26749314/242933? It seems like less code and still correct.

Comment: That code does not work correctly for characters consisting of more than one UTF-16 code point, e.g. Emojis. – As an example, if the text field contains the text "" and you delete that character, then `range` is `(0,2)` because `NSRange` refers to the  UTF-16 characters in an `NSString`. But it counts as *one* Unicode character in a Swift string. – `let end = advance(start, range.length)` from the referenced answer does crash in this case with the error message "fatal error: can not increment endIndex".

Comment: Hmm... OK. Thanks. I think I'll just [convert String to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26517690/242933) then as that seems to work and is less code (simpler).

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: Sure. My intention was to answer the verbatim question *"How can I convert NSRange to Range<String.Index> in Swift"* in a Unicode-safe way (hoping that someone might find it useful, which is not the case until now :(

Comment: @user1687195: Thanks for fixing my stupid error in the Swift 2 code! I should have tested it.

Comment: @MartinR hello, i've added your solution into another swift file and when calling textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange in get the error String? has no member 'rangeFromNSRange', please help. thanks

Comment: @DrPatience: That probably means that `textField.text` is now an *optional* and has to be unwrapped ...

Comment: In sample. For let n1 I need to put let n1:NSrange to work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Range<String.Index> does not have members upperBound or lowerBound anymore and utf16.index does not exist either. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ClockWise: Which Xcode version? Did you see the "Update for Swift 3" at the end of the answer?

Comment: @MartinR I have 7.3.1, not sure if my version applies to the Update for Swift 3-section you wrote. But the 2.0 seems to work so I'll use that for now. Thanks for this brilliant answer.

Comment: @ClockWise: Yes, Xcode 7.3.1 is Swift 2.2. Xcode 8 is Swift 3.

Comment: Thank you, once more, for doing Apple's work for them. Without people like you, and Stack Overflow, there's no way I'd be doing iOS/OS X development. Life's too short.

Comment: where did you find the documentation?

Comment: @jiminybob99: Command-click on `String` to jump to the API reference, read all methods and comments, then try different things until it works :)

Comment: For ``let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex)``, I think you actually want to limit it by ``utf16.endIndex - 1``. Otherwise, you can start off the end of the string.

Comment: @MichaelTsai: That is interesting. I would have expected that `utf16.index(from16, offsetBy: nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex)` returns `nil` if `from16 == utf16.endIndex`, but it doesn't, and that causes the crash. I have changed to code so that it should work correctly now. Please let me know if you still find any issues, and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: In Swift 4, there are now dedicated initialisers for this :) You can use `Range(nsRange, in: str)` to convert an `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>?` and `NSRange(range, in: str)` to perform the reverse (and actually the `NSRange` initialiser can take an arbitrary `RangeExpression` with a `String.Index` bound, so for example can also deal with partial ranges).

Comment: @Hamish: OK, thanks for the notice! It seems that I have to update some answers (which I will do as soon as  I have the time). Do you know if that change went through a proposal (because I did not see one). Or is it part of the recent `String` changes?

Comment: @MartinR No I don't recall seeing it in an evolution proposal – I only found out about it through watching the "What's new in Foundation" WWDC session. Unfortunately, they don't *appear* to be documented yet, so I don't know if you should hold off updating until they are – but [their location in the source is here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSRange.swift#L116) (and PR [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9709)).

Comment: @ViniApp: Thank you for the edit suggestion. However, there is already a Swift 4 version, using the now available built-in methods. Please let me know if that does not work for you.

Comment: For those that came here for index calculations: In large strings, index offset calculation can become expensive. Using `from16` as a starting point, you can speed this up as: `let to16 = utf16.index(from16, offsetBy: nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex - 1)`

Comment: This also does not work if I try to replace such ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) character set

Comment: @Alexander: I replaced  with ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) in my above example, and it worked as expected.

Comment: @MartinR yes, of course. Please have a look at https://github.com/alexanderkhitev/TestTextView I made a demo project and made a string which is a UIViewController property (in the project it is needed for later use) if I delete characters for example from (つ ͡ ° ͜ʖ ͡ °) つ, then I get the app crash, of course you can make guard, but then we do not we can remove this character set. Also there are problems if in the middle of a set of characters (like I wrote above) insert emoji and start deleting, then you can get such a result ͜͡ and it can not be deleted any more.

Answer (score 23):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/829739) by Martin R seems to be correct because it accounts for Unicode.

However at the time of the post (Swift 1) his code doesn't compile in Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7), because they removed `advance()` function. Updated version is below:

#### Swift 2

```
extension String {
    func rangeFromNSRange(nsRange : NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        let from16 = utf16.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location, limit: utf16.endIndex)
        let to16 = from16.advancedBy(nsRange.length, limit: utf16.endIndex)
        if let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: self) {
                return from ..< to
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

#### Swift 3

```
extension String {
    func rangeFromNSRange(nsRange : NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        if let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let to16 = utf16.index(from16, offsetBy: nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: self) {
                return from ..< to
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

#### Swift 4

```
extension String {
    func rangeFromNSRange(nsRange : NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You need to use `Range<String.Index>` instead of the classic `NSRange`. The way I do it (maybe there is a better way) is by taking the string's `String.Index` a moving it with `advance`.

I don't know what range you are trying to replace, but let's pretend you want to replace the first 2 characters.

```
var start = textField.text.startIndex // Start at the string's start index
var end = advance(textField.text.startIndex, 2) // Take start index and advance 2 characters forward
var range: Range<String.Index> = Range<String.Index>(start: start,end: end)

textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is similar to Emilie's answer however since you asked specifically how to convert the `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` you would do something like this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

     let start = advance(textField.text.startIndex, range.location) 
     let end = advance(start, range.length) 
     let swiftRange = Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end) 
     ...

}
```

Comment: The characters view and UTF16 view of a string may have different lengths. This function is using UTF16 indexes (that's what `NSRange` speaks, though its components are integers) against the string's characters view, which may fail when used on a string with "characters" that take more than one UTF16 unit to express.

Answer (score 5):

A riff on the great answer by @Emilie, not a replacement/competing answer.
(Xcode6-Beta5)

```
var original    = "This is a test"
var replacement = "!"

var startIndex = advance(original.startIndex, 1) // Start at the second character
var endIndex   = advance(startIndex, 2) // point ahead two characters
var range      = Range(start:startIndex, end:endIndex)
var final = original.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString:replacement)

println("start index: \(startIndex)")
println("end index:   \(endIndex)")
println("range:       \(range)")
println("original:    \(original)")
println("final:       \(final)")
```

Output:

```
start index: 4
end index:   7
range:       4..<7
original:    This is a test
final:       !his is a test
```

Notice the indexes account for multiple code units. The flag (REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTERS ES) is 8 bytes and the (FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY) is 4 bytes. (In this particular case it turns out that the number of bytes is the same for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 representations.)

Wrapping it in a func:

```
func replaceString(#string:String, #with:String, #start:Int, #length:Int) ->String {
    var startIndex = advance(original.startIndex, start) // Start at the second character
    var endIndex   = advance(startIndex, length) // point ahead two characters
    var range      = Range(start:startIndex, end:endIndex)
    var final = original.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: replacement)
    return final
}

var newString = replaceString(string:original, with:replacement, start:1, length:2)
println("newString:\(newString)")
```

Output:

```
newString: !his is a test
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       let strString = ((textField.text)! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.0 assuming `func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {`:

```swift
var oldString = textfield.text!
let newRange = oldString.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)..<oldString.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location + range.length)
let newString = oldString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(newRange, withString: string)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    guard let current = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: current) else {
        return false
    }
    
    let text = current.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
    // ...
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best effort. But this cannot check or detect wrong input argument.

```
extension String {
    /// :r: Must correctly select proper UTF-16 code-unit range. Wrong range will produce wrong result.
    public func convertRangeFromNSRange(r:NSRange) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let a   =   (self as NSString).substringToIndex(r.location)
        let b   =   (self as NSString).substringWithRange(r)

        let n1  =   distance(a.startIndex, a.endIndex)
        let n2  =   distance(b.startIndex, b.endIndex)

        let i1  =   advance(startIndex, n1)
        let i2  =   advance(i1, n2)

        return  Range<String.Index>(start: i1, end: i2)
    }
}

let s   =   ""
println(s[s.convertRangeFromNSRange(NSRange(location: 4, length: 2))])      //  Proper range. Produces correct result.
println(s[s.convertRangeFromNSRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 4))])      //  Proper range. Produces correct result.
println(s[s.convertRangeFromNSRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))])      //  Improper range. Produces wrong result.
println(s[s.convertRangeFromNSRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))])      //  Improper range. Produces wrong result.
```

Result.

### Details

`NSRange` from `NSString` counts UTF-16 *code-unit*s. And `Range<String.Index>` from Swift `String` is an *opaque* relative type which provides only equality and navigation operations. This is intentionally hidden design.

Though the `Range<String.Index>` seem to be mapped to UTF-16 code-unit offset, that is just an implementation detail, and I couldn't find any mention about any guarantee. That means the implementation details can be changed at any time. Internal representation of Swift `String` is not pretty defined, and I cannot rely on it.

`NSRange` values can be directly mapped to `String.UTF16View` indexes. But there's no method to convert it into `String.Index`.

Swift `String.Index` is index to iterate Swift `Character` which is an *Unicode grapheme cluster*. Then, you must provide proper `NSRange` which selects correct grapheme clusters. If you provide wrong range like the above example, it will produce wrong result because proper grapheme cluster range couldn't be figured out.

If there's a guarantee that the `String.Index` *is* UTF-16 code-unit offset, then problem becomes simple. But it is unlikely to happen.

### Inverse conversion

Anyway the inverse conversion can be done precisely.

```
extension String {
    /// O(1) if `self` is optimised to use UTF-16.
    /// O(n) otherwise.
    public func convertRangeToNSRange(r:Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
        let a   =   substringToIndex(r.startIndex)
        let b   =   substringWithRange(r)

        return  NSRange(location: a.utf16Count, length: b.utf16Count)
    }
}
println(convertRangeToNSRange(s.startIndex..<s.endIndex))
println(convertRangeToNSRange(s.startIndex.successor()..<s.endIndex))
```

Result.

```
(0,6)
(4,2)
```

Comment: In Swift 2, `return  NSRange(location: a.utf16Count, length: b.utf16Count)` must be changed to `return  NSRange(location: a.utf16.count, length: b.utf16.count)`

Answer (score 1):

I've found the cleanest swift2 only solution is to create a category on NSRange:

```
extension NSRange {
    func stringRangeForText(string: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let start = string.startIndex.advancedBy(self.location)
        let end = start.advancedBy(self.length)
        return Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end)
    }
}
```

And then call it from for text field delegate function:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let range = range.stringRangeForText(textField.text)
    let output = textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    // your code goes here....

    return true
}
```

Comment: I noticed my code was no longer working after the latest Swift2 update. I've updated my answer to work with Swift2.

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer I find the optionals cumbersome. This works with Swift 3 and seems to have no problem with emojis.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
      shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
      replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  guard let value = textField.text else {return false} // there may be a reason for returning true in this case but I can't think of it
  // now value is a String, not an optional String

  let valueAfterChange = (value as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
  // valueAfterChange is a String, not an optional String

  // now do whatever processing is required

  return true  // or false, as required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {

    func nsRange(of string: String) -> NSRange? {
        guard let range = self.range(of: string) else {  return nil }
        return NSRange(range, in: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `NSRange`, when used in `NSString` operations, represents positions of the UTF-16 units. Then the shortest way to convert to `String.Index` is to initialise via `String.Index(utf16Offset: Int, in: StringProtocol)` initialiser.

```swift
let string = "...."
let nsRange = NSRange(....) // This NSRange belongs to `string` variable.
let range = String.Index(utf16Offset: nsRange.lowerBound, in: string)
        ..< String.Index(utf16Offset: nsRange.upperBound, in: string)
```

Example:

```swift
let string = "a-\u{1112}\u{1161}\u{11AB}--\u{E9}\u{20DD}-‼--(العلاجية)-f"
let rangeOfLeftParenthesis = (string as NSString).range(of: "(")
let rangeOfRightParenthesis = (string as NSString).range(of: ")")
print("string: \(string)")
let lowerBound = String.Index.init(utf16Offset: rangeOfLeftParenthesis.upperBound, in: string)
let upperBound = String.Index.init(utf16Offset: rangeOfRightParenthesis.lowerBound, in: string)
let arabicSentenceRange = lowerBound ..< upperBound // Instance of `Range<String.Index>`
print("arabicSentenceRange: \(string[arabicSentenceRange])")
```

Output:

```
string: a-한--é⃝-‼--(العلاجية)-f
arabicSentenceRange: العلاجية
```

Answer (score -1):

The Swift 3.0 beta official documentation has provided its standard solution for this situation under the title **String.UTF16View** in section *UTF16View Elements Match NSString Characters title*

Comment: [Here's the link to Apple Docs > String.UTF16View > UTF16View Elements Match NSString Characters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/utf16view#2848381)

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5 Solution**

Short answer with main extension

```swift
extension NSRange {

    public init(range: Range<String.Index>, 
                originalText: String) {

        self.init(location: range.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: originalText),
                  length: range.upperBound.utf16Offset(in: originalText) - range.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: originalText))
    }
}
```

For [detailed answer check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468499/2740218)

Comment: If you are using `utf16Offset` then worth to use `Range<String.UTF16View.Index>` instead of `Range<String.Index>`.