# Swift UITextChecker

Tags: xcode, string, swift, uitextview, uitextchecker

I am trying to use `UITextChecker` in my Swift project. The code below currently has an error on the last line:

```
    var checker:UITextChecker = UITextChecker()
    var textLength = countElements(textView.text)
    var checkRange:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, textLength)

    var misspelledRange:NSRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(textView.text, range: checkRange, startingAt: checkRange.location, wrap: false, language: "en_Us")

    var arrGuessed:NSArray = checker.guessesForWordRange(misspelledRange, inString: textView.text, language: "en_US")!

    var correctedStr = textView.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(misspelledRange, withString: [arrGuessed.objectAtIndex(0)])
```

The error says:

```
'NSRange' is not convertible to 'Range<String.index>'
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index

Comment: I am not sure how to adapt this to my case. Do you know what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

The `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` method you're using expects `Range<String.Index>` to be passed in, not `NSRange`. You can't use `misspelledRange` because it's the wrong type. The link in the possible duplicate comment ([NSRange to Range<String.Index>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index)) has examples of deriving a `Range<String.Index>` from an `NSRange` or casting `text` to `NSString`, whose `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` method *does* use `NSRange`.