# Swift - validating UITextField

Tags: swift, validation, uitextfield

I have these outlets in my app:

```
@IBOutlet var name1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var name2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var name3: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var name4: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var newButton: UIButton!
```

What I tried to do is the following:

Every time the user types something in one of these four `UITextField`s or deletes something, I want to check if any `UITextField` is empty

If any `UITextField` is empty, the button should be disabled.

If all `UITextField`s are set (not empty), the button should be enabled.

My code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    setButton()

    return true
}

func setButton() {

    let inputValid = checkInput()

    if inputValid {

        newButton.enabled = true

    } else {

        newButton.enabled = false

    }

}

func checkInput() -> Bool {

    let name1Value = name1.text
    let name2Value = name2.text
    let name3Value = name3.text
    let name4Value = name4.text

    if !name1Value.isEmpty && !name2Value.isEmpty && !name3Value.isEmpty && !name4Value.isEmpty {

        return true

    }

    return false

}
```

Ok, it works 50% for now.

When I type one character in each `UITextField`, the button is still disabled.

When I add a second one to any `UITextField`, the button gets enabled etc...

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use this, which is called every time a key is pressed:

```
name1.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
name2.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
name3.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
name4.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)


func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    if name1.text?.isEmpty || name2.text?.isEmpty || name3.text?.isEmpty || name4.text?.isEmpty {
        //Disable button
    } else {
        //Enable button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**
 - Here is how I have solved it trying to avoid long conditionals
 - This will also allow you to do realtime validation on each individual textfield, unlike the accepted answer, you can update your UI according to what the user is typing.

```
let textfields : [UITextField] = [name1, name2, name3, name4]
for textfield in textfields {
  textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}


@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
  //set Button to false whenever they begin editing
  yourButton.isEnabled = false
  guard let first = textFields[0].text, first != "" else {
        print("textField 1 is empty")
        return
    }
    guard let second = textFields[1].text, second != "" else {
        print("textField 2 is empty")
        return
    }
    guard let third = textFields[2].text, third != "" else {
        print("textField 3 is empty")
        return
    }
    guard let forth = textFields[3].text, forth != "" else {
        print("textField 4 is empty")
        return
    }
    // set button to true whenever all textfield criteria is met.
    yourButton.isEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: This is the straightforward way to do validation. With shouldChangeCharactersInRange there is a risk to get stuck with a big number of variations: user pastes a text, user enters in the mid of text or deletes in the mid of text - they all have to be taken into account. But with textFieldDidChange we just have the end result and can validate it as is.

Comment: I managed to work with that by using `let nsString = textField.text as NSString?` and `let newString = nsString?.replacingCharacters(in: shouldChangeCharactersIn, with: replacementString)` which gives you the newString. You can then validate that and return `true` or `false` as required. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index)

Answer (score 0):

The textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange: method gets called BEFORE the contents of the text field have changed.

You should special-case the current text field and figure out if it's new contents are going to be blank after the edit.

Something like this:

```
textField.text.length > range.length - replacementString.length
```

(That's off the top of my head, and not debugged. Plus you would have to come up with logic that makes sure all the other fields are non-blank, and use the logic above to test the contents of the current field.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UITextFieldValidator](https://github.com/anukooll/TextFieldValidator). I have created a validator which covers almost each validation required in an app. Also its in swift. So go ahead and check it out.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: @iAnurag , very nice, but the code will still give error if textfield starts with number but contains alphabets also. so what should be the solution of this???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope you will get what to do.

```
func updateSaveButtonState() {
    let text = titleTextField.text ?? ""
    saveButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty
}


@IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    updateSaveButtonState()
}

@IBAction func returnPressed(_ sender: UITextField) {
    titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4 & 5

Firstly, you create a function like `setupTextFields()` and you call it in `viewDidLoad()` (something like this):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    setupTextFields() //You call the function here.
}

func setupTextFields() {
    name1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    name2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    name3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    name4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
}
```

Then you create another function which each time you press a key, that function will be called. I'll show you two options, then you choose which fits better for you. Usually, *Option 1* would be considered a better implementation for Swift.

**Option 1**

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard !name1.text!.isEmpty else {
        button.isEnabled = false
        return
    }
    guard !name2.text!.isEmpty else {
        button.isEnabled = false
        return
    }
    guard !name3.text!.isEmpty else {
        button.isEnabled = false
        return
    }
    guard !name4.text!.isEmpty else {
        button.isEnabled = false
        return
    }
    button.isEnabled = true
}
```

**Option 2**

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if name1.text!.isEmpty || name2.text!.isEmpty || name3.text!.isEmpty || name4.text!.isEmpty {
        button.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        button.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```