# Make a user access a view only after it has completed an action IOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I make that an user can only access a View only after he/she has completed an action? For example, only access a view if the user has responded correctly to a question in a previous view in Swift 3 for IOS development

Comment: That's a very broad question without code. What is your viewController doing? Is it a quiz app where the same stuff's being shown over and over or are you doing some sort of authentication where you're segueing to a new viewController once your question is answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but the physics for poets version is you'd want to add some sort of target action method to monitor your `textField`. One the question is answered, the user can segue.

One approach would be to have a "next" button that's initially disabled and enabled once the question is correctly answered.

In `FirstViewController`, you could have an `IBOutlet` to a `nextButton` and a `textField`, like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
```

You'd also control+drag a segue to `SecondViewController`

Then, in `viewDidLoad`, you could disable the button initially:

```
nextButton.isEnabled = false
```

You can't segue when the button is disabled. The moment it's enabled, you can segue by pressing it.

Then, you could have a [method you create to monitor your `textField`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31495915/4475605) for a correct answer:

```
// this is the method that monitors your textField
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {

    if textField.text != "42" {
        nextButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    else {
        nextButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`, you'd add a target action after your disable `nextButton`. Here's what `viewDidLoad` looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // this sets the button to disabled...
    nextButton.isEnabled = false

    // this monitors the textField for the correct answer
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
}
```

Here's [a repo I created for you](https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/ConditionalSegue/tree/master/ConditionalSegue).

Comment: thank you so much!! I have been struggling with this one but everything is clear now! thank you really much! :D

Comment: If that helped you, please accept the answer and click up the up arrow :)