# UITextView User Input Text Validation in Swift 4 or Swift 5: Restrict the specific characters in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

Need help on how to do a text input validation to a UITextView. Many help is there for UITextField, but I can't find the right solution for this textView input validation. My expectation is to a UITextView needs to accept only these characters[A-Za-z0-9.-] what to do any help or solution. My textView is connected to the ibOutlet, Made it as self, even added the subclass as UItextViewDelegate still I can't find solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swift - validating UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495188/swift-validating-uitextfield)

Comment: ANSWER(Bcoz i can't answer to my question) PART 1
 #1.Created a Public String Property 
    var isValidComment: Bool {           //Special Characters Input Validation
           let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 .-")
           return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil
        }

Comment: ANSWER Part 2
#2. Then i validated the UITextView/textView field with this string validation property with an error text. That's it.
    
    if !eventComments.text.isValidComment {
                    errorLabel.text = "Please enter Event Comments between 4 - 60 Characters"
                } else {
                    errorLabel.text = "Allowed Event Comments Characters are a-z A-Z 0-9"
                }

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is at least one character that not conforms to the **alphanumeric** characterSet.

The method:

```
yourTextView.text.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
```

should return **nil** if there is no alphanumeric character.