# String.Index(_:within:) initializer crashing

Tags: string, swift

I've been messing around a bit with `String` indexes lately and I had a hard time figuring things out and something still bugs me.

I'm trying to use `init(_:within:)`'s method of type `String.Index`. It works great when I'm using an `utf16index` inside the bounds of the string but when outside it crashes with this message :

> fatal error: Invalid String.UTF16Index for this UnicodeScalar view

Now I get it's a requirement to the function as stated in the doc :

```
/// - Requires: `utf16Index` is an element of
///   `characters.utf16.indices`.
```

**Actual question : What I don't get is why crashing when this `init` is a failable initializer? Shouldn't it return `nil`?**

*I'll probably make a method checking if the index can be in the string but still it sounds strange to me.*

Comment: Actually I overlooked that requirement when writing http://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415, I fixed it now, after reading your question.

Comment: @MartinR Pretty funny since my question comes originally from me implementing your solution to this question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full header documentation for that method is

```
extension String.CharacterView.Index {

    // ...

    public init?(_ unicodeScalarIndex: UnicodeScalarIndex, within characters: String)
    /// Construct the position in `characters` that corresponds exactly to
    /// `utf16Index`. If no such position exists, the result is `nil`.
    ///
    /// - Requires: `utf16Index` is an element of
    ///   `characters.utf16.indices`.
    public init?(_ utf16Index: UTF16Index, within characters: String)

    // ...

}
```

So there are two different failure reasons:

- The given `utf16Index` is outside of the range of valid indices of
  `characters.utf16`. This violates the requirement and causes a runtime 
  exception.
- The given `utf16Index` is a valid index of `characters.utf16`, but
  there is no character position corresponding to that index.
  In that case the method returns `nil`.

As an example, consider the string "ab". It consists of three characters,
but four UTF-16 code units:

```
let str = "ab"
str.characters.count // 3
str.utf16.count // 4
Array(str.utf16) // [97, 55357, 56447, 98]
```

(See also [Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30)
in the Swift blog.)

The UTF-16 indices `0`, `1`, `3` correspond to a valid character position,
but `2` does not:

```
String.Index(str.utf16.startIndex, within: str) // 0
String.Index(str.utf16.startIndex + 1, within: str) // 1
String.Index(str.utf16.startIndex + 2, within: str) // nil
String.Index(str.utf16.startIndex + 3, within: str) // 3
```

Actually the "one past the end" position (`utf16.endIndex`) is also valid (and that is not apparent to me
from the header documentation), in that case `characters.endIndex` is returned:

```
String.Index(str.utf16.startIndex + 4, within: str) // 4
str.characters.endIndex // 4
```

But everything beyond `endIndex` causes a runtime exception:

```
String.Index(str.utf16.startIndex + 5, within: str) // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

To compute an UTF-16 index that is inside the valid bounds, you can use
the 3-parameter form of `advance()`

```
let i16 = advance(str.utf16.startIndex, offset, str.utf16.endIndex)
```

Comment: I was pretty sure it had something to do with characters taking more than one UTF16 code unit and your really complete answer explained it great. Thanks a lot ;)