# Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected type 'Range<Index>'(aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')

Tags: ios, swift, nsrange

Getting this error when checking the range for string characters...

```
@objc func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let shouldChange = false
    let text = textField.text
    var newString = text!.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as? NSString
    if newString.length > 14{
        newString = newString.substringToIndex(14)
    }
    textField.text = newString.uppercaseString

    return shouldChange
}
```

Comment: Compare [NSRange to Range<String.Index>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index).

Answer (score 34):

Instead of `text!` say `(text! as NSString)`.

```
var newString = (text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as? NSString
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let oldString = textField.text {
        let newString = oldString.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: oldString)!,
                                                      with: string)
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```