# TextField delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Why doesn't the shouldChangeCharactersInRange update the textfield right away. It is 1 delayed by one character.

For example, download this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/goljs3d6lcxutxy/UITextField%20Tutorial.zip?dl=0

add the following code to

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

method

```
print(textField.text)
```

see how it is delayed by one character. I want it to be updated as I type the text not one delayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is asking you if it should take the `replacementString` and add it onto `textField.text`. It is called immediately after you press a key on the keyboard and before letter appears on screen.

To see what the new string will be, you'd need to to something like this.

```
let newText = textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
print(newText)
```

Comment: I got an error message saying Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected type 'Range<Index>'(aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>'). Googled it and it lead me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769753/cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsrange-aka-nsrange-to-expected-type-range

Problem is fixed. @Clever Error, you da man! Thanks!