# Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range<Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')

Tags: swift, nsrange

I Have a error in my code like "Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range' (aka 'Range')" but I don't know how to solve this please any one help me?

Here I post my code.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Hey I have started using this Chat App", forKey: "Status")
            var strNumber: String = txtPhoneNumber.text!
            var myRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 2)
            var myRange1: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
            var ran: String = strNumber.substringWithRange(myRange)  ------>  //This line error shows.
            var ran1: String = strNumber.substringWithRange(myRange1)
            if (ran == "00") || (ran == "60") || (ran == "62") || (ran == "65") || (ran == "91") || (ran == "44") {
                strNumber = strNumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(ran, withString: "") as String
            }
            else if (ran1 == "0") {

                strNumber = strNumber.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(ran1, withString: myRange1) as NSString
                //str_number = str_number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(ran1, withString: "", options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch, range: myRange1)
            }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should convert `strNumber` to NSString: `var strNumber: NSString = txtPhoneNumber.text!`

More here: [NSRange to Range<String.Index>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is useful for me...@courteous

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4:**

First typecaste to a string, and then use the class method on this typecasted string

```
let typeCasteToStringFirst = textField.text as NSString?
let newString = typeCasteToStringFirst?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

Answer (score 1):

`substringWithRange` method works for `NSString` type

```
var strNumber: String = txtPhoneNumber.text!
```

change above line

```
var strNumber: NSString = txtPhoneNumber.text as! NSString
```