# shouldChangeCharactersInRange Range.length Always 0

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Question: For some reason in the TextField Delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange the range.length is always 0...

My Code

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var shouldChange = true
        let newSubjectString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        let newCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: newSubjectString as String)
        let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0
        if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
            return false
        }

        if newSubjectString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) >= 3 {
            return false
        }
        return true
}
```

I am trying to get rid of the "Undo Bug" (When paste doesn't pass my validation then i try to shake, to Undo, and then the app crashes).. though whenever I check the range.length in this function.. it is always 0. Though this same fix did work in other areas of my app.

To clarify... it is not a crash that I am looking to fix... the fix for the crash is supposed to be the following lines(Which work in other places of my app):

```
let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0
if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
    return false
}
```

The issue I am having is that in a specific controller when using the ^ sanity check.. it is not always accurate because range.length is always 0 in this delegate method.

[**A note on the crashing "undo" bug**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1773257/5748651)

> As is mentioned in the comments, there is a bug with UITextField that
>   can lead to a crash.
>
> If you paste in to the field, but the paste is prevented by your
>   validation implementation, the paste operation is still recorded in
>   the application's undo buffer. If you then fire an undo (by shaking
>   the device and confirming an Undo), the UITextField will attempt to
>   replace the string it thinks it pasted in to itself with an empty
>   string. This will crash because it never actually pasted the string in
>   to itself. It will try to replace a part of the string that doesn't
>   exist.
>
> Fortunately you can protect the UITextField from killing itself like
>   this. You just need to ensure that the range it proposes to replace
>   does exist within its current string. This is what the initial sanity
>   check above does.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: It's length will be different from 0 if you select some text with long press and press any letter on the keyboard.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the crash. Which line exactly causes the crash? What is the error of the crash?

Comment: It is not so much the crash i am worried about.. as the following lines usually take care of it: `let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0 if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){ return false}` I am more concerned about why the range.length is always 0 no matter what text i type in

Comment: Though if you do want to know the crash i added that check for it is: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'` it seems to be coming from the `let newSubjectString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)` again this probably has to do with the range length being 0

Comment: I suggest you read through some of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index

Comment: sadly there doesn't seem to be anything  in regards to my issue in that post :(