# shouldChangeCharactersInRange gives different range with emoji

Tags: swift, emoji, uitextfielddelegate

If I implement the method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` there is some kind of inconsistency between the value on range and the text size.
When I have the textfield with only one common letter (like "a") and press backspace the text to be replaced is an empty string, `textField.text!.characters.count` returns 1 and the rage has position 0 and length 1 (which everything makes sense), however if the text field has just a emoji (like ""), `range.length` returns 2 rather than 1, and then I have a crash when casting range from `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>`. Why does it happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSRange to Range<String.Index>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index) – String and NSString ranges are different, and you cannot simply "cast" between them.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0+**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let strtext = textField.text else {
        return true }

    let completeString = (strtext as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let increment = string == "" ? 0 : 1

    let finalString = (completeString as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(location: 0, length: range.location + increment))

    print(finalString)

    return true
}
```

> > **Note: - This will gives the string with range *startIndex* to cursor position**