# Reliable function to get position of substring in string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, encoding

This is working well for English:

```
public static func posOf(needle: String, haystack: String) -> Int {
    return haystack.distance(from: haystack.startIndex, to: (haystack.range(of: needle)?.lowerBound)!)
}
```

But for foreign characters the returned value is always too small. For example "का" is considered one unit instead of 2.

```
posOf(needle: "काम", haystack: "वह बीना की खुली कोयला खदान में काम करता था।") // 21
```

I later use the 21 in `NSRange(location:length:)` where it needs to be 28 to make `NSRange` work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Swift `String` is a collection of `Character`s, and each `Character`
represents an "extended Unicode grapheme cluster".

`NSString` is a collection of UTF-16 code units.

Example:

```
print("का".characters.count) // 1
print(("का" as NSString).length) // 2
```

Swift `String` ranges are represented as `Range<String.Index>`, 
and `NSString` ranges are represented as `NSRange`.

Your function counts the number of `Character`s from the start
of the haystack to the start of the needle, and that is different
from the number of UTF-16 code points.

If you need a "NSRange compatible"
character count then the easiest method would be use the
`range(of:)` method of `NSString`:

```
let haystack = "वह बीना की खुली कोयला खदान में काम करता था।"
let needle = "काम"

if let range = haystack.range(of: needle) {
    let pos = haystack.distance(from: haystack.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
    print(pos) // 21
}

let nsRange = (haystack as NSString).range(of: needle)
if nsRange.location != NSNotFound {
    print(nsRange.location) // 31
}
```

Alternatively, use the `utf16` view of the Swift string to
count UTF-16 code units:

```
if let range = haystack.range(of: needle) {
    let lower16 = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: haystack.utf16)
    let pos = haystack.utf16.distance(from: haystack.utf16.startIndex, to: lower16)
    print(pos) // 31
}
```

(See for example
[NSRange to Range<String.Index>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index/30404532#30404532) for more methods to convert between `Range<String.Index>`
and `NSRange`).