# distance(from:to:)' is unavailable: Any String view index conversion can fail in Swift 4; please unwrap the optional indices

Tags: swift, swift4

I was trying to migrate my app to Swift 4, Xcode 9. I get this error. Its coming from a 3rd party framework.

> distance(from:to:)' is unavailable: Any String view index conversion can fail in Swift 4; please unwrap the optional indices

```
func nsRange(from range: Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
    let utf16view = self.utf16
    let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16view)
    let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16view)
    return NSMakeRange(utf16view.distance(from: utf16view.startIndex, to: from), // Error: distance(from:to:)' is unavailable: Any String view index conversion can fail in Swift 4; please unwrap the optional indices
                       utf16view.distance(from: from, to: to))// Error: distance(from:to:)' is unavailable: Any String view index conversion can fail in Swift 4; please unwrap the optional indices
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/2083655

Comment: Swift 4 has built-in methods to convert between String and NSString ranges, therefore you don't need that extension anymore. Have a look at the latest update to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415.

Comment: really great, glad I saw your comment, almost missed :) thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can simply unwrap the optional indices like this:

```
func nsRange(from range: Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange? {
    let utf16view = self.utf16
    if let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16view), let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16view) {
       return NSMakeRange(utf16view.distance(from: utf16view.startIndex, to: from), utf16view.distance(from: from, to: to))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error says that the distances you are generating are optionals and need to be unwrapped. Try this:

```
func nsRange(from range: Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange {
    let utf16view = self.utf16
    guard let lowerBound = utf16view.distance(from: utf16view.startIndex, to: from), let upperBound = utf16view.distance(from: from, to: to) else { return NSMakeRange(0, 0) }
    return NSMakeRange(lowerBound, upperBound)
}
```

However the return could be handled better in the `guard` statement. I'd recommend making the return type of the function `NSRange?` and checking for nil wherever you call the function to avoid inaccurate values being returned.

Comment: Its throwing error `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String.UTF16View.IndexDistance' (aka 'Int')`

Answer (score -1):

Please check :

```
let dogString = "Dog‼"
let range = dogString.range(of: "")!
```

// This is using Range

```
let strRange = dogString.range(range: range)
print((dogString as NSString).substring(with: strRange!)) // 

extension String {
    func range(range : Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange? {
        let utf16view = self.utf16
        guard
            let from = String.UTF16View.Index(range.lowerBound, within: utf16view),
            let to = String.UTF16View.Index(range.upperBound, within: utf16view)
        else { return nil }
        let utf16Offset = utf16view.startIndex.encodedOffset
        let toOffset = to.encodedOffset
        let fromOffset = from.encodedOffset
        return NSMakeRange(fromOffset - utf16Offset, toOffset - fromOffset)
    }
}
```

// This is using NSRange

```
let strNSRange = dogString.range(nsRange: NSRange(range, in: dogString))
print((dogString as NSString).substring(with: strNSRange!)) // 

extension String {
    func range(nsRange: NSRange) -> NSRange? {
        guard
            let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let to16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let from = from16.samePosition(in: self),
            let to = to16.samePosition(in: self)
            else { return nil }
        return NSMakeRange(from.encodedOffset, to.encodedOffset)
    }
}
```