# how to convert Range to NSRange in swift 4

Tags: swift, range, swift4, nsrange

This is my swift 3 code:

```
extension String {

    func nsRange(from range: Range<Index>) -> NSRange {
         let lower = UTF16View.Index(range.lowerBound, within: utf16)
         let upper = UTF16View.Index(range.upperBound, within: utf16)
         return NSRange(location: utf16.startIndex.distance(to: lower), length: lower!.distance(to: upper))
    }
}
```

When i migrated to swift 4 it is giving me error distance(to:) is unavailable

Any solution

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index/30404532#30404532

Comment: @JonSnow i want to convert Rang<String.Index> to NSRange

Comment: @chetanpanchal: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415 to the "duplicate" shows both conversions: NSRange to String Range and vice versa.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks resolved my problem

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks