# cannot convert value of type nsrange to range

Tags: ios, swift, migration

How can I convert NSRange to Range in Swift?

```
var copyRange = NSRange()
            copyRange.location = 0
            copyRange.length = 44
            var tmpAudioData = NSMutableData()

            tmpAudioData.appendData(audioPlayer.data?.subdata(in: copyRange)) //<- error at this line
```

Comment: Try `let range = Range(copyRange, in: audioPlayer.data!)!`. Related, the most voted answer by Martin (not the accepted one by Alex) of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index