# Replace Substring with Markdown on NSTextView in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, substring, nstextview

*Swift 5, Xcode 11*

In a Stack Overflow text editor, you can select some text (like "selected" below), click the **bold** button, and it replaces:

```
Text selected here.
```

...with this:

```
Text **selected** here.
```

I'm trying to pull off the same thing with an `NSTextView` using Swift 5.

I can get the `selectedRange` of the text like this:

```
@IBAction func clickBold(_ sender: NSButton) {
  let range = content.selectedRange() //content is my NSTextView
}
```

But I can't figure out how to proceed from here. I found `replaceSubrange` but it seems to accept only a `Range<String.Index>` and not an `NSRange`.

```
@IBAction func clickBold(_ sender: NSButton) {
  let range = content.selectedRange() //content is my NSTextView
  var markdownText = content.string
  markdownText.replaceSubrange(range, with: "**\(markdownText)**") 
}
```

Has anyone done this before and can help me see what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415 for conversions between `NSRange` and `Range<String.Index>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`replaceCharacters(in:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstext/1530589-replacecharacters) method of `NSText` (whose subclass `NSTextView` is).

```
@IBAction func clickBold(_ sender: NSButton) {
  let range = content.selectedRange()
  let selectedText = (content.string as NSString).substring(with: range)
  content.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "**\(selectedText)**") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `replaceCharacters` looks pretty handy. It looks like I still need to parse the substring out of `markdownText`, though. This replaces the selected portion with the entire string. Using my example above, it turns it into `Text **Text selected here.** here.`

Comment: @CliftonLabrum my bad, forgot to get the selected substring from the whole `NSTextField`, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this works:

```
let range = content.selectedRange()
markdownText = content.string

if let index = Range(range, in: markdownText){
  content.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "**\(markdownText[index])**")
}
```

It provides the selected text snippet I need to wrap it in `** **`. @MartinR's linked SO post helped me see that I can convert the string index with `Range()`.